# Chrome - Colspan not working as expected

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, html-table

I have this code:

```
<tr>
    <td width="40%" align="left" class="form_cell">
    <span class="sub_header">Update or Delete</span><br />
    Please select whether you would like us to update this contacts details, or delete them from the system.
    </td>

    <td width="60%" align="left" class="form_cell">
    [class=form__parser func=updateDetails__updel(150.$update_or_delete$.true)]
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="100%" align="left" colspan="2" id="ammend_contact_details" style="display: none;">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" align="left">
            <tr>
                <td width="40%" align="left" class="form_cell">
                <span class="sub_header">New Title</span><br />
                            Please enter the contacts new title, IE Mr, Mrs, Dr, Miss, Ms
                </td>

                <td width="60%" align="left" class="form_cell">
                <input type="text" name="update_contact_title" class="input" size="48" maxlength="6" value="$update_contact_title$" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The code which start with `[class=form__parser...]` creates a drop down list. If you click one of the options, the cell below it (`ID ammend_contact_details`) is displayed, otherwise its hidden.

The website address for this page is: http://www.westlandstc.com/index.php?plid=6#eyJwbGlkIjoiNTkiLCJjbGlkIjoiNDQ2Iiwic2NsaWQiOiJudWxsIiwiZHluYW0iOiJudWxsIiwiYXBwSWQiOiJudWxsIn0= and the element in question is at the very bottom of the page.

The problem is, the `colspan`attribute works fine in internet explorer (surprise surprise), however, in Chrome, all the content which is supposed to be spread over the 2 parent columns, only goes into the 1st column.

I have narrowed the bug down further, if I remove the `style="display: none"` attribute it works fine. Everytime I try to change either the display style or visibility style, Chrome places everything back into the first column.

In addition, I tried setting the background colour of the cell which spans 2 columns to red. In internet explorer, again this works as expected. In chrome, no background-color is displayed.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Just a quick thing, you have "colspan='3'" when there's only two columns. Would that be anything to do with it?

Comment: Sorry @jamie-wilson That was just me testing something. It was originally set to colspan='2' but wondered if changing it to 3 would change anything.

Comment: Could you give a small example of your final code, instead of the link and the "this code creates" ? The easier it is for us to see an example of it going wrong, the easier it is to help. Maybe make an example in jsfiddle or something?

Comment: Hi @Nanne Thanks for the reply, however its now working as expected, the issue was setting the display attribute to display: table-cell instead of inline/block.

Comment: If you can it would still be great to update the question to reflect what you had, so the question + answer are more complete?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What are you setting the 'display' property to in order to show it?  iirc you would need to use 'display:table-cell' (or similar - can't remember the exact value) in order for chrome to treat it as a table cell

Comment: Its javascript which changes the display attribute to 'inline'. I've tried block and inline to no avail, however I will try table-cell (or similar) now.

Comment: Just tried table-cell and it works as expected :) Thank you very very very much!!!

Answer (score 3):

> style.display=''

works for me with chrome.

> 'display:table-cell'

does not

Answer (score 2):

Rather than adding the CSS property `display:inline` to the `<td>`, which for some reason IE is happy with and Chrome is not, I would update your JavaScript to just remove the `display:none` style and let the browser's default `display:table-cell` take affect.

In the `<select name="update_or_delete">` onchange method simply have:

```
if(this.value=='Update') { 
  document.getElementById('ammend_contact_details').style.display='';
} else { 
  document.getElementById('ammend_contact_details').style.display='none';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't seem to respect `colspan` unless it has at least 1 row exactly matching number of columns in the table. I tried to make a grid with 2 items in 1st row and 3 items in 2nd row. **For Firefox** that's all you need:

```css
td {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="width: 50%">box 1.1</td>
    <td colspan="3" style="width: 50%">box 1.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="width: 33.33%">box 2.1</td>
    <td colspan="2" style="width: 33.33%">box 2.2</td>
    <td colspan="2" style="width: 33.33%">box 2.3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But it **doesn't work on Chrome and Edge**, even though all `<td>`s have default styling: `display: table-cell`. To fix it you need to add empty row with exact match for column count so it finally looks like this:

```css
td {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="width: 50%">box 1.1</td>
    <td colspan="3" style="width: 50%">box 1.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="width: 33.33%">box 2.1</td>
    <td colspan="2" style="width: 33.33%">box 2.2</td>
    <td colspan="2" style="width: 33.33%">box 2.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="visibility: hidden">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```